# Songs & instrument Game Alternative (Stepmania & Guitar Hero)

Tags: games

I am looking in Ubuntu for alternatives to Stepmania an Guitar Hero. I used Stepmania with Wine but I heard there was a Linux version for it. Same for Guitar Hero where I can connect the playable guitar and enjoy. Are there an alternative for this 2 and if so which ones.

Comment: GH = Frets on Fire http://fretsonfire.sourceforge.net/  and yeah, there are linux builds of StepMania...  http://www.stepmania.com/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend [Performous](http://performous.org/), it is a all-in-one music game.
It can import songs from `Frets On Fire` (like Guitar Hero/Rock Band)
and songs from `UltraStar Deluxe` (Like SingStar/karaoke)

Offtopic:
You can use real Guitar Hero Guitars from the Wii in the game.
Connect the wiimote using `wminput` and map the guitar-keys to the keyboard-keys you use in the game.

Have Fun !